# Обнуление json при перезаписи

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, база-данных, dump

Есть код

```
import json
up = 5
with open("test.json", "w") as write_file:
    json.dump(up, write_file)
```

Он записывает значение переменной up в файл test.json
Но можно заметить, что файл test.json обнуляется( = 0 байт) во время выполнения строчки:

```
with open("test.json", "w") as write_file:
```

Это можно нагляднее увидеть, если добавить задержку перед командой dump:

```
import json
import time
up = 5
with open("test.json", "w") as write_file:
    time.sleep(1)
    json.dump(up, write_file)
```

Это нормально, так как после обнуления в него записываются новые данные. Но

Тогда при аварийном закрытии программы появляется вероятность потерять содержимое json файла

Есть ли какие-нибудь стандартные и не очень способы избежать это?

Comment: Записать в другой временный файл, а потом после записи переместить временный файл на место основного

Comment: Переместить вручную?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один вариант, для особо ценных данных:

- переименовываете старый `json` в другое имя (в конце приписываете дату-время этого переименования)
- записываете новый `json` в обычное имя.

Плюсы:

- у вас есть все версии `json`, всегда можно откатиться на какую-то из них

Минусы:

- тратиться место

Другой вариант, с экономией места:

- копируете старый `json` в имя.old
- пишете новый `json` в обычное имя
- удаляете старый `json` совсем

Плюсы:

- у вас практически при любом развитии событий есть `json` с обычным его именем (ну или хотя бы имя.old, если процесс записи как-то сломался)

Минусы:

- хранится только одна, последняя версия `json` (ну или две версии - имя.old можно не стирать)

Можно ещё как-то комбинировать эти и другие варианты. Например, можно архивировать старые версии в `zip` архив через неделю и т.п., как это обычно делают с нужными логами.